# How to download a file from server and start a download process at client side

Tags: http

I want to download a file from my server upon a form submit by the client.
I have no problem creating the form in the client side, but have no idea how and what to return from the server to the client which will start a file download process...

Thanks,
Omer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you'd like the user to see some kind of file download dialog? That's a rather trivial issue.

Just submit the file name before sending the actual contents (i.e. as part of the HTTP headers) when processing the form's `action`:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=YourDownload.txt
```

This will cause the browser to show a file download dialog, defaulting to `YourDownload.txt` rather than the script name shown in the URL.

Keep in mind that special characters in the file name should be escaped similar to URI encoding (i.e. a `%` followed by the hex code). Otherwise it might be ignored by the browser.

[More Information on this header field can be found here under section 19.5.1.](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.5.1)

Comment: what about the Content-Length?
This is the response I'm sending (used chrome tools to view it)
200 OK
Date: Wed, 24 Apr 2013 09:43:05 GMT
Server: PasteWSGIServer/0.5 Python/2.7.3
Content-Disposition: attachment
Content-Length: 0
Filename: c:/res.tda
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Comment: You should add that to your question, the comment format kills the formatting. Also keep in mind that `filename=` is a Parameter of `Content-Disposition`. It's **not** a header on ist own.